# Can the Hierophant use the Inspired Spell feature to cast domain spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, domains, mythic-adventures

Does the Inspired Spell feature from the [Hierophant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths-paizo-inc/hierophant/) mythic path allow you to cast what would otherwise be a domain-only spell?

The [Inspired Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths-paizo-inc/hierophant/#TOC-Inspired-Spell-Su-) feature says:

> You can expend one use of mythic power to cast any one divine spell, treating your caster level as 2 levels higher. This spell must be on your divine spell list (or your domain or mystery spell list) and must be of a spell level that you can cast using that divine spellcasting class. If you are a spontaneous spellcaster, you don’t need to have the spell prepared, nor does it need to be on your list of spells known. Using this ability does not expend a prepared spell or available spell slot. You can apply any metamagic feats you know to this spell, but its total spell slot level must be a slot level you can normally cast.

For an example, let's look at the [*spike stones*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spike-stones/) spell. It's Druid 4 / Shaman 4 / Earth Domain 4. As it's a domain spell, it is technically a divine spell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes, but only if you have that domain.

[Inspired Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths-paizo-inc/hierophant/#TOC-Inspired-Spell-Su-) says:

> You can expend one use of mythic power to cast any one divine spell, treating your caster level as 2 levels higher. *This spell must be on your divine spell list (or **your domain** or mystery spell list)* and must be of a spell level that you can cast using that divine spellcasting class. If you are a spontaneous spellcaster, you don’t need to have the spell prepared, nor does it need to be on your list of spells known. Using this ability does not expend a prepared spell or available spell slot. You can apply any metamagic feats you know to this spell, but its total spell slot level must be a slot level you can normally cast.

Emphasis mine. Inspired spell allows you to cast any divine spell that meets one of these three requirements:

- It's on your class's spell list.
- It's on your domain's spell list.
- It's on your mystery's spell list.

So you could use it to cast [Spike Stones](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spike-stones/) as a cleric, if you have the [Earth Domain](https://aonprd.com/DomainDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Earth), otherwise you wouldn't be able to do so.